# Kepler’s First Law - Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In book Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos, chapter 13, section 13.5, addresses on Kepler’s First Law of following way:

Theorem. (Kepler’s First Law) The path of a particle moving under the
influence of Newton’s law of gravitation is a conic of eccentricity
$$
\epsilon = \sqrt{1+2\ell^{2}E}.
$$
This path lies along a hyperbola, parabola, or ellipse according to whether $E >0$,
$E =0$, or $E <0$.

**Remark: $E$ is the energy and $\ell$ is the angular momentum**

Doubt:

(1) We know that Kepler’s First Law says Orbits are elliptical, whith sun at one focus. So in the theorem shouldn't it be exactly $E < 0$? Which is the case where we have an ellipse.

(2) In the theorem, what guarantees that the orbits are elliptical? For example, the earth revolves around the sun in an elliptical motion with the sun at one focus. How does the theorem guarantee this? How can I get from this theorem the claim that the planets make elliptical orbits around the sun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $E = 0$ would correspond to an eccentricity of $1$. This is a parabola. In this equation, having $E \in (-\frac{1}{2l^2},0)$ will give an ellipse: eccentricity between $0$ and $1$.

I think the confusion is in the definition of Kepler's 1st law. Most authors will use it to say planents orbit in ellipses with the sun at one of the foci.

However, the word orbit can also mean *any* trajectory passing by the object creating the gravitational field. So hyperbolic/parabolic trajectories where the particle approaches the sun but goes off to infinity count too.

Comment: Yes, It was a typo, I meant $E < 0$.

Comment: E < 0 just on its own does not correspond to an ellipse. You also need a lower bound so that the eccentricity  (defined to be a number greater or equal than 0) does not become an imaginary number.

Comment: In the theorem, what guarantees that the orbits are elliptical?

Comment: This author is using orbit in a different sense than a closed curve. So they are not saying Kepler's first law = Orbits are elliptical.

Comment: So how can I get from this theorem the claim that the planets make elliptical orbits around the sun?

Comment: Just specify the interval of allowable energies I gave. During the formation of the solar system, anything that had an energy not within in this range would have been ejected, and so everything that's left is in an elliptic orbit. Elliptic orbits - and hence this range of energies - are the only "periodic orbits" in terms of dynamical systems.